# Elastic Search Multiple Filter values for the same field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

Say that I have to filter cars constructors in a Elastic Search Index (ES 7.15), where the field `car_maker` is mapped to `keyword`, having it a limited number of possibilities among car makers string names:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "car_maker": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}

GET /cars/_search
{

    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
                "term": {
                    "car_maker": "Honda"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

This, along with a matching query will work ok. The `filter` will not participate to score calculation as desired.
Now I would like to to filter more car makers for that query (let's say a `should` query):

```
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter" : [
            {"term" : { "car_maker" : "Honda"}},
            {"term" : { "car_maker" : "Ferrari"}}
        ]
    }
 }
}
```

this is not going to work. I will have any error from ES query engine, but any result too. Of course is always possibile to apply more filters to different fields like `car_maker` and `car_color`, but how to do the opposite: apply more values (`Honda`, `Ferrari`, etc.) to the same filter field `car_maker` like in the example above, without conditioning the score calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the following filter query:

```json
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : {
        "terms" : {
          "car_maker" : ["Honda", "Ferrari"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, basically it's what now is referred to `Terms Query` - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html - that can be applied to `filter` too!